# Values initialized from a chain of futures

Tags: scala, future

Consider a following snippet of code:

```
class MyClass {
  var a = _
  var b = _
  ...
  var y = _

  val z = (for {
    a0 <- someMethodReturningFuture
    b0 <- someMethodReturningFuture(a0)
    ...
    z0 <- someMethodReturningFuture(y0)
  } yield {
    a = a0
    b = b0
    ...
    y = y0
    someCalculation(y)
  }).result
}
```

Is it possible to perform such an initialization but using `val`s instead of `var`s (somehow)? The point is, I don't want to block and wait for every intermediate result, just for the last one.

Comment: Note that putting methods resulting futures in the for comprehension which not actually depend on *all* previous values is not a good idea, since the start of their computation will be deferred even if logically they could be started.

Comment: Also, if not needed, avoid blocking and `.result`. Return the `Future` instead and let the caller chain or get the result if it really needs it (there are situations where the caller only wants to react asynchronously, so the blocking is totally unnecessary)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you have more than 22 variables:

```
val (a, b, c, d, ..., v) = (for {
  a0 <- someMethodReturningFuture
  b0 <- someMethodReturningFuture(a0)
  ...
  u0 <- someMethodReturningFuture(t0)
} yield {
  (a0, b0, ..., u0, someCalculation(u0))
}).result
```

Comment: I had a thought of it, but didn't like the limit of 22 values. It's not that I'm going to have more than 22, it just doesn't look that cool to me :)

Comment: Well, you can always do some fancy match nesting when you need more than 22: `val (abc@(_ ,_ ,_), d, e) = ((a0, b0, c0), d0, e0); val (a, b, c) = abc`.

Comment: An advice from Jack Bauer for having more than 22 values: refactor, NOOW! :)

Answer (score 3):

Could you delay the `result` evaluation by using `lazy` values ? Something like:

```
class MyClass {

  lazy val a = myFutures.a.result
  lazy val b = myFutures.b.result

  private val myFutures = new AnyRef {
    val a = someMethodReturningFuture
    val b = a.map( a0 => someMethodReturningFuture(a0) )
  }

}
```

All futures are created at initialisation without blocking, but you will block the first time you actually try to use a result.

Comment: Looks like a good solution. But lazy evaluation introduces some overhead, doesn't it?

Comment: Not really. It is handled by a simple bitmap field. I did some benchmark of lazy evaluation on another similar problem and the overhead is not measurable.

Comment: The problem with lazy vals is of course that they won’t even try to calculate the result in the background unless asked for it.

Comment: @Debilski. It depends of the future implementation you are using, but most I've used start to compute when as soon as the future is defined. The computation itself is not behind a lazy val, only the get operation.

Comment: @paradigmatic: Ok, but only if you access the `object`, I think. Otherwise this will be lazy as well.

Comment: @Debilski: You are right, one has to access the `object` to start the computation

Comment: @SergeyWeiss: Indeed, here is a fixed version. The `myFutures` instance is now initialized when the `MyClass` instance is initialized.